# What is the difference between users added to mysql with the host set to 127.0.0.1 vs localhost?

Tags: mysql, localhost

I noticed that there are always entries for a root user with host set to `127.0.0.1` and another with the host set to `localhost`. My question is why are there two entries, four if you include `MACHINE_NAME`, and `::1`, where MACHINE_NAME is the actual machine name, like appServer2.

I've wondered why there are multiple entries though. Are there machines where `localhost` is does not resolve to `127.0.0.1`? Are their times where running mysql would try to connect via the servers "external" interface?

I've seen this question before, but no one has answered why '127.0.0.1' and 'localhost' are always separate entries.

Comment: They're separate because you don't need your localhost to be set to 127.0.0.1, but that is the default. For 99% of people it is the same, but you have the capability if for some reason you desire to change what localhost means.

Comment: In MySQL on unix systems, the hostname `localhost` has a special meaning. In MySQL, `user@localhost` doesn't ever resolve to an IP address, 127.0.0.1 or otherwise. It identifies a connection through a local Unix socket file.

Answer (score 5):

In MySQL on unix systems, `localhost` is a special value. It is used to identify connections through a local socket, *not* TCP/IP.

(Confusingly, outside of MySQL, the hostname `localhost` typically resolves to IP address 127.0.0.1. To reduce confusion, think of "localhost" in MySQL as meaning something entirely different. It might better have been named "local_socket_ connection".)

Those are separate entries because "localhost" will never refer to a TCP/IP connection, and an IP address will never refer to the local socket.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html

> The default host name is `localhost`. On Unix, this has a special meaning, as described later.

---

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name `localhost` specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs. For connections to `localhost`, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file. This occurs even if a `--port` or `-P` option is given to specify a port number. To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the local server, use `--host` or `-h` to specify a host name value of `127.0.0.1`, or the IP address or name of the local server. You can also specify the connection protocol explicitly, even for localhost, by using the `--protocol=TCP` option. For example: